# Replace tab bar button in UITabBar with a UIButton

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an application in tabbar, but I need to put a UIButton insted of a tabbar button. There are 4 tabbarbuttons in it, I want to replace the one with UIButton. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do...

Comment: Reason to replace with UIButton?

Comment: reason is ,user want a click action in tabbar item

Comment: why do you want to replace that with UIButton ?

Comment: @jhaliya ,because the client want to put a tabbar item like button for click event.he needs the button in the tabbar ,,thats why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use UIButtton instead of tabbar, use all four tabs. Make one tab blank and put a button of same size at same view on which you want to replace.

Comment: but i cant put uibutton in tabbar ,i made a tab blank and put a uibutton in it,but it will show on the view of this blank tab

Comment: not UI button in it. Put the button upon the tab. it will cover the tab, not with in the tab.

Comment: have you tried ? it will done there, when the tab will appeared, then code for button to cover the tab.

Comment: @singsan,,i tried but nothin happn.i thnk i misunderstand what u say,please give me some detail about it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean toolBar instead of tabBar (otherwise this question makes no sense; see below), just save the items in an NSMutableArray and replace the object at index i with whatever you wish to replace it with, then set the new array as the toolBar items once again.

You can figure out all the details of doing this by reading the [UIToolbar Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In short, I'm suggesting something along the lines of this:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:toolBar.items];
[tmpArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:myButton];
[toolBar setItems:tmpArray animated:YES];
```

**Why does it make no sense to put a button in a tabbar?**

Well, a few reasons. You can't is probably the best. Another good one is that any action you want for the would-be button can be put instead into the `viewWillAppear` method of the viewController that appears when that tabbar selection is made.

Comment: You **cannot** add a button to a tabbar no matter how hard you try (unless you create a custom tabbar subclass, but I bet even that won't get past Apple's approval process). You  **can** use a toolBar instead, as I suggest above.