# iphone tabbar application doubts

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone tabbar application doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226297/iphone-tabbar-application-doubts)

How can we replace a tabbar item in a tababar application with a uibutton ,i have 4 tabbar items and i have to replace the second tabbar iteam with a uibutton for action click.

thankz in advance